# Angular 2 - Observe result of firebase database

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I'm new in angular, so be kind :)

Angular 2 ( 1.0.4 )
Angular Cli
NodeJs 7.9

i've try to make a centralized service that check if user is logged-in and, if it is retrive and send back data of User... i just try for 2 days to make this method works without success... any help will be appreciated :

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
    import { AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import { TipoUtente } from './tipidati' ;
    import {Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router} from '@angular/router';

    import * as firebase from 'firebase';

    import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise' ;


    @Injectable()
    export class StatoutenteService implements OnInit {

constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {}

public getUserData() : Observable<any> {

  this.afAuth.authState.map( auth => {

        if (auth == null) {
          this.Logged = false ;
          this.Utente = new TipoUtente() ;
          this.UId = '' ;
          return undefined ;

        } else {
          this.Logged = true  ;
          this.UId = auth.uid ;

          return this.dbUserData().then(data => {
              console.log('leggo promessa') ;
              console.log(data) ;
              if (data.Livello != undefined) this.Utente = data ; else this.Utente = undefined ;
              console.log(this.Utente) ;
              if ( this.Utente == undefined ) { this.createNewUser() }
            } ) ;
        }
      } ) ;


} ;

private dbUserData() : Promise<TipoUtente> {

  // Controllo Utente
  console.log('Recupero dati utente!') ;
  console.log('UID :' + this.UId ) ;
  console.log(this.Logged) ;

  let utenteX = this.db.object('users/' + this.UId)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // must import 'rxjs/add/operator/first'; before using it here
    utenteX.subscribe( data  => {
      if ( data.$value == null ) resolve(undefined); else resolve(data) ;
    }, reject);
  });

}
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: hello Tim, thanks for answer... it just doesn't work because code had some error... answer of @ShabbY was really usefull  ... now i just need to make it works for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that your getUserData() does not returning anything. You need to return the ovservable.

```
return this.afAuth.authState.map( auth => { ....
```

then you should be able to access the userData by subscribing the getUserData() like so:

```
this.statoutenteService.getUserData().subscribe(promisedUserData => {...})
```

but actually mixing promises and observables is not a good practice. try to restructe it like so:

```
export class StatoutenteService implements OnInit {
    Logged: boolean;
    UId: string;
    Utente: TipoUtente;

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
         this.Logged = false;
         this.UId = '';
         this.Utente = new TipoUtente();
    }

    public getUserData() : Observable<any> {

      return this.afAuth.authState
         .filter(auth => !!auth)  //filters out events where auth is not truthy
         .flatMap( auth => {      //flatMap will resolve the returned observable (chaining observables)
             this.Logged = true;
             this.UId = auth.uid;

             return this.db.object('users/' + this.UId);
        }).map(data => {
             if (data.Livello != undefined)  
                 this.Utente = data; 
             else 
                 this.Utente = undefined;
             console.log(this.Utente) ;
             if (this.Utente == undefined)  
                 return this.createNewUser();
             return null; 
        });
    }
}
```

then you don't have the overhead of the promise. when you then subscribe to the getUserData() observable, you will get whatever the last maping function returns. so right now you would get the return value of this.createNewUser(); if this.Utente was undefined before. otherwise null.

you would access it the same way, by subscribing to it:

```
this.statoutenteService.getUserData().subscribe(user => {...})
```

Hope that will help you.

Comment: this works nice! i'm very new in angular and typescript i didn't know the flatmap method!  :) i've post my updated code :) with second issue :)

Answer (score -1):

Hello thanks for the answer :) i just edit a bit for make works for me and now the result is much better. then my previous code ( thankssss!! )

I just need now that listener receive back an "empty" user when is not auth... i try to edit your code as up but i get an exeption.

so i TRY to make this schema :

1. Menubar call the service asking for UserData
2. If User is Logged : Menubar get userdata and update buttons depending on Level
3. if User is not Logged : Menubar show "Login" button and hide menu.

this is edited code so far :

SERVICE :

```
      public getUserData() : Observable<any> {

        return this.afAuth.authState
           .flatMap( auth => {      //flatMap will resolve the returned observable (chaining observables)
               if ( auth == null ) {
                 this.Logged = false;
                 return undefined ;  // <<< Angular doesn't like this because it expect a stream
               } else {
               this.Logged = true;
               this.UId = auth.uid;
               return this.db.object('users/' + this.UId);
               }
          }).map(data => {
               console.log('sono dentro data') ;
               console.log(data) ;
               if (data.Livello != undefined) {
                   console.log('sono dentro if') ;
                   this.Utente = data;
               } else {
                   this.Utente = undefined; }
               console.log(this.Utente) ;
               if (this.Utente == undefined) return this.createNewUser(); else return data ;
          });
      }

private createNewUser() : Observable<any> {

  // Creo utente
  console.log('Creo Utente!') ;
  console.log(this.Logged) ;

  // se non sono loggato ritorno Livello 0
  if ( !this.Logged ) { return undefined } ;

  // carico dati in Utente :
  this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
    if (auth != undefined) {
    console.log('sono in MAP') ;
  this.Utente = new TipoUtente() ;
  this.Utente.Cognome = auth.displayName.split(" ")[0] ;
  this.Utente.Nome    = auth.displayName.split(" ")[1] ;
  this.Utente.DisplayName = auth.displayName ;
  this.Utente.Immagine = auth.photoURL ;
  this.Utente.Livello = 1 ;
  this.UId = auth.uid ;

  // scrivo utente :
  console.log('chiamo DB') ;

  return this.db.database.ref('users/' + auth.uid).set(this.Utente) ;
  }
}) ;
```

MENUBAR :

```
this.StatoUtente.getUserData().subscribe(data => {

    this.Utente = data ;
    console.log(data) ;

    if ( data != undefined ) {
        this.btntext = "Accedi" ;
        this.LevelMenu = 0 ;
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/') ;

      } else {
        this.btntext = "Logout" ;

        this.Utente = data ;
        this.LevelMenu = this.Utente.Livello ;
      }
    })
```

Comment: Hey Riccardo, this is not how stack overflow is supposed to work. You should not post an answer to your old question that contains a new question. When first question is resolved, mark the answer that resolved your problem as correct answer, and create a new question. The purpose of that is that anyone with a similar problem could find the requestion and the related answer with ease. so good questions are described in a gerenic fashion

Comment: regarding your second problem. try the following scheme:  1. user is not logged by default, you show the login button.  2. request user data 3. update only if user is logged in

Comment: hello ShabbY sorry i didn't want to make anyone angry or upset.. the point is that your answer make my code works but i didn't solve my problem :) because at some point user can decide to logout and i need to reflect this to the Navbar component ;) i've accept your solution in any case... just i've post new answer that don't have "return null; " because cause an exception

Comment: if it is related to your previous question, just make an update to your question next time and append your new question. another solution to you problem might be to return an new Observable() instead of undefined within the flatMap block

Comment: ok next time i'll update my answer... i didn't know that is that the correct flow ;)